# Draw "Game Over" using a TxtEntity class

Tags: java

I want to be able to draw on the screen "Game Over" when the game is finished. My teacher wants me to create a new class called TxtEntity with its own constructor and from that draw "Game over" and I'm having problem figuring out what to do. I'm using the MVC concept and I've tried to create a method as is shown in the code, but it doesn't work. And my Game Controller can't implement the method even though I have implemented TxtEntity to it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import se.egy.game.model.Sprite;

public abstract class TxtEntity extends Sprite{

    public TxtEntity(Image image, int x, int y, String text) {
        super(null, x, y);

    }

    public void GameOver(Graphics g) {  
            g.drawString("GAME OVER", 2, 3);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));    
    }

}
```

Here is where I want to implement the game over method (where it says TxtEntity.)

```
    public void checkCollisionandRemove() {
        for (int i = 1; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
            if (entityList.get(i).collision(player)) {
                entityList.remove(entityList.get(i));
            }
        }

        if (entityList.size() == 1) {
            //System.exit(1);
            resetkeyDown();

            player.setDirectionX(0);
            player.setDirectionY(0);

            TxtEntity.
        }

    }
```

When there is only 1 entity left (the player) I want say "Game Over" on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make gameOver method "static" so you won't need to create an object for it(currently you don't have an object for it so you can't call the method).

```
    public static void gameOver(Graphics g) {  
            g.drawString("GAME OVER", 2, 3);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));    
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```
TxtEntity.gameOver
```

Also a little note method names start with lower case and each first letter of a new word after that is upper case 
Example:

methodNameOne

thisIsMethodTwo

Comment: I tried that but it wants me to write "TxtEntity.gameOver();" and if I enter something in () it gives me an error message, and otherwise it just gets red marked

Comment: If you decided to make gameOver a static method, then you need to provide an object `Graphics` as an argument, without it it will not work. Take a look into `Sprite`. Check if `Sprite` its a class or an abstract class. Plus, check if it has a `paint` or `draw` method. You may have to override it when you extend it.

Comment: Yeah sprite is an abstract class, and yeah it has a drawImage method, but what do you mean with "you need tp provide an object graphics as an arugment"?

Answer (score 0):

@L.lsen

Your TxtEntity its an abstract class. This means that you cannot instantiate it by itself. You must extend it.

You could create an anonymous class extending the abstract class TxtEntity:

```
TxtEntity te = new TxtEntity(null, x, y, ""){};
```

Or you could create a class that extends the abstract class. Then, instantiate the such class:

```
class GameOverEntity extends TxtEntity {
  public GameOverEntity(x, y){
    super(null, x, y, "");
  }
}
...
GameOverEntity gameOver = new GameOverEntity(x, y);
```

My advise is for you to review abstract classes, interfaces, and anonymous classes (in case you don't want to create a new class that extends the abstract class).

Let me know if this makes sense to you.